# What is the proper way to add parskip to a document class?

Tags: spacing, parskip

In the documentation for the `parskip` package, it says :

> [The `parskip` package] still is and will remain an inferior choice compared to a properly designed document class.

What is the proper way to incorporate parskip into a custom class?

In particular, how should section headings, theorem environments, etc. be modified to produce regular spacing?

Comment: It just means that you should design the entire document layout by looking at what you want, rather than designing the layout for the case with no vertical par separation, and then having an automated fixup to adjust the display spaces when you increase the paragraph spacing.

Comment: Just as a note: The document classes in KOMA-script provide a class option (`parskip`) for this.

Comment: As @Skillmon says: The best way is to start with a KOMA-script or memoir class, typeset a complicated document with the parskip option of your choice, and then proofread the document looking for issues you have to improve.

Comment: Are you wanting to typeset to a grid --- text lines on a page match with text lines on a facing/backing page? BTW `memoir` effectively includes the `parskip` package.

Comment: Is there a way to measure spacing other than by eyeballing it?

Comment: @PeterWilson No. But when I use parskip it seems like my theorems, headings, etc. are no longer spaced correctly, so I'm looking for some general guidelines about how to fix it.